# Create Telerik Reporting list object

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

Just started out using Telerik Report Designer and like to create a PDF using the details section bound to a list object. I created a people  list object and add name and phone extension.

> I dont see how to bound the list to the detail section and call the design file.

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
            people.Add(new Person(501, "Joe"));
            people.Add(new Person(302, "Bill"));
            people.Add(new Person(263, "Tom"));
            people.Add(new Person(244, "Mark"));
            people.Add(new Person(567, "Jim"));
            people.Add(new Person(662, "Jen"));

            Telerik.Reporting.ReportParameter reportParameter1 = new Telerik.Reporting.ReportParameter();
            reportParameter1.AvailableValues.DataSource = people;
            var reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
            var reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.TypeReportSource();
            string documentName = "NCCN Telephone List";


            var deviceInfo = new System.Collections.Hashtable();

            deviceInfo["OutputFormat"] = "PDF";


            Telerik.Reporting.Processing.RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", reportSource, deviceInfo);

            string fileName = result.DocumentName + "." + result.Extension;
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);

            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detail section cannot be bound to data itself - it uses the data from the datasource of the report. The code above will not generate a report, because it just binds the data in the list to the report parameter, but not to the report itself. The code also uses [TypeReportSource](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/t-telerik-reporting-typereportsource), but doesn't set its TypeName, hence the reportProcessor instance would likely throw an exception. I don't have Telerik Reporting installed to provide a tested solution, but basically you need to do this:

- Add two textboxes to the report's detail section and set their
  expression to "=Fields.Id" and "=Fields.Name" (assuming the Person
  class has these properties).
- The list of Person instances must be
  assigned as report datasource. Since you're doing it
  programmatically, you need to use [InstanceDataSource](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/t-telerik-reporting-instancereportsource) and the code should look like this:

  ```
  var report = new MyReport();
  report.DataSource = people;
  var irs = new InstanceReportSource(){ ReportDocument = report };
  var reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
  var result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", irs, null);
  ```
- Save the result.DocumentBytes to some path of your choice.
  The approach is shown in Reporting's documentation in [How to: Bind to a BusinessObject](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/object-data-source-how-to-bind-to-business-object), In that example the report source is passed to the viewer, instead to the reportProcessor, but the idea is the same.